# Compser: can I specify install directory for some dependencies?

Tags: composer-php

I have a `composer.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/laravel": "4.2",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.0",
        "twig/twig": "1.13.1"
    }
}
```

After running `composer install` this is what my directory structure would look like:

```
/composer.json
/vendor/laravel
/vendor/wordpress
/vendor/twig
```

After running `composer install` I want my directory to look like this:

```
/composer.json
/laravel
/wordpress
/vendor/twig
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use post-install-cmd to move things around. But in general this is a bad idea. It is better to keep all vendor stuff in one folder. After moving things around there will be problems with autoloader.

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/laravel": "4.2",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.0",
        "twig/twig": "1.13.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "mv vendor/laravel .",
            "mv johnpbloch/wordpress ."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: But this also puts all of the other composer directories in the root directory. Is adding all the other directories to the `mv directory-name` post-install-cmd the only way of going about this?

Comment: Then do it the other way. Let vendor-dir be the default and move laravel and wordpress from vendor to root in post-install-cmd.